# Check RPC Encrypted Data in motion on HDFS/YARN/Spark/Hbase

Tags: apache-spark, encryption, hdfs, hbase, rpc

We have specific requirement to check/validate data in motion when RPC encrypted data flows for all communication with client as well as within big data components like HBase/Phoenix/HDFS/YARN/Hive processes.

Please suggest ideas to do validation for data in motion or 
Is there readily available solution to make sure motion of data on ports and RPC communication are encrypted.

Comment: One way : read the packets for tcpdump/wireshark and compare the encrypted and non-encrypted data in motion. However, this quite a raw approach to do packet analysis on ports/ethernet. Please suggest a better way !!

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is a better forum if you want a recommendation for software packages.

Comment: I am seeking tools/tricks instead of licensed version softwares. so, I believe I could get the better answer from big data open source forum here.  I saw your profile with expertise in Cloudera. Please help.